# grep returns no matches for following expression

Tags: regex, grep

Using the `(?<=_)(.*)(?=\.)` regex with the `23353_test.txt` test string returns nothing with grep with the `-p` option. It doesn’t show errors either. I expect the return to be test. But when the regex  is tried in regex101.com it runs correctly.

Comment: Are you using `-p` or `-P`? It should be the latter, and you need a GNU grep. Have you got  a GNU grep? See https://ideone.com/sLmy03

Comment: Yes with capital -P it works but it still returns the . and _ with the match.

Comment: How come? Have you seen the [demo link](https://ideone.com/sLmy03)? What is your `grep --version | head -n 1`?

Comment: Yes it does work now but the returned match is _test. .In regex101 it is just test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following **GNU** `grep` command extracts the right substring:

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=_).*(?=\.)' file
```

Note that `.*` matches greedily, and if you want to make sure you match a substring between the closest `_` and `.` you need to use a

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=_)[^._]*(?=\.)' file
```

where `[^._]*` matches zero or more chars other than `.` and `_`.

If you cannot rely on your `grep`, you can use `sed` here:

```sh
sed -n 's/.*_\(.*\)\..*/\1/p' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/JYTVlo):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='23353_test.txt'
grep -oP '(?<=_)(.*)(?=\.)' <<< "$s"
# => test
sed -n 's/.*_\(.*\)\..*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => test
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** You should use `awk` for this requirement, please try following as per your shown samples. Setting field separators as `_` OR `.` and checking condition if number of fields are 3 then printing 2nd field here.

```
s='23353_test.txt'
echo "$s" | awk -F'[_.]' 'NF==3{print $2}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` program here with using capturing group capability of `sed`. Using `-E` option to enable ERE in `sed` then in main program using regex `^[^_]*_([^.]*)\..*`, which matches from starting till 1st occurrence of `_` and creating 1st and only capturing group which has everything which comes between `_` and `.` in it and after it matching literal `.` till end of line. Then while substituting  whole line with 1st capturing group value.

```
s='23353_test.txt'
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[^_]*_([^.]*)\..*/\1/'
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` using `awk`'s `match` function here. Using regex inside `match` function to match betwen 1st occurrence of `_` till `.` comes and having it inside a capturing group, we are using array named `arr` which will store captured values in it, so printing 1st capturing group value by `arr[1]` in it.

```
echo "$s" | awk 'match($0,/^[^_]*_([^.]*)\..*$/,arr){print arr[1]}'
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** Using GNU `grep` here, where using its `-o` and `-P` options. Where `-o` option is for printing matched part only and `-P` flag is for enabling PCRE regex. Here is [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/RxcGtn/1) for following regex.

```
echo "$s" | grep -oP '^.*?_\K([^.]*)(?=\.\S+$)'
```